# What is "Amazon Linux 2023" default username?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

What is AWS ec2 "Amazon Linux 2023" default username?
'ec2-user' is not working

previous versions of Amazon Linux, including Amazon Linux 2, the default username is "ec2-user"

but 'ec2-user' is not working in 2023 version

Comment: According to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/cloud-init.html it should still be `ec2-user`

Comment: Same problem for me. Use a "modern" EC key (vs RSA key) the ec2-user is not working for me, while trying to use a 2023 AMI image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always go to `Connect > EC2 Instance Connect`. The Username filled by AWS is usually the default one you can use to connect.

I created an instance of `Amazon Linux 2023` and `ec2-user` was the default username...

Comment: Thanks. I'll try again. Not connecting is another problem..

Comment: No connection can be for several reason. If your instance doesn't have an IP Address, it should be in a private subnet which route all the request to a NAT Gateway. If so you can use SSM to connect.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else is struggling with this, deep in the Amazon Linux 2023 documentation, there's a section that says RSA-based keys are not supported when connecting to Amazon Linux 2023 instances. In practical terms, this means that if you're reusing an old key pair, it probably won't work on new Amazon Linux 2023 instances.

Unfortunately, the messaging surrounding this is pretty unclear - so it won't be obvious that you're using the **right** username and key pair but its being rejected based on the host key algorithm.

If this is happening to you, I suggest you generate a new key pair and give that a go.

More info available here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/ssh-host-keys-disabled.html